# Issues with textarea's scrollheight increasing inconsistently

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

This issue is not very easy to explain so I apologize if this question seems confusing.

Basically, I have a `<textarea>` who's height changes based off its value.  If there is any vertical overflow (which would normally produce a vertical scrollbar), I increase the height of the `<textarea>` to match its `scrollHeight` property.  This seems to work just fine for the first two lines, but when more text is added, I noticed that the point at which the `scrollHeight` increases is different for each line of text.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the strange behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/2zpkf6fL/2/

Type about 5 or 6 lines of text and you will see what I'm talking about.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?  Why does the `scrollHeight` increase at different points for different lines of text?

Comment: works fine for me in latest Chrome

Comment: I tried it in the latest version of chrome and firefox and they both show the strange behavior.  What OS are you using?  Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: I'm using OSX. Seems fine for me even in Firefox.

Comment: You can only really see the issue clearly when there's like 5 or 6 lines of text.  On the 5th line, the textarea will increase its size when my cursor hits the center.  If you type like 20 lines, you should see that theres like 2 or 3 completely empty lines below your text.  Do you not see this at all?

Comment: I'm on OSX too.  Strange that you don't see what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i do what you are looking to do.

HTML:

```
    <div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="textarea-size"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
  /* you should change this*/
  width: 50%;
}

textarea, .textarea-size {
  min-height: 25px;
  /* need to manually set font and font size */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;

  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  resize:none;

  /*
  "pre" or "preline" or "normal" fixes Chrome issue where
    whitespace at end of lines does not trigger a line break.
  However, it causes the text to exhibit the behavior seen with
    "pre" that is described below.
   */
  white-space: normal;
}

.textarea-size {
  visibility: hidden;

  /*
  Pre-wrap: preserve spacing and newlines, but wrap text.
  Pre: preserve spacing and newlines but don't wrap text.

  "pre" does not wrap well on Firefox, even with word-wrap:break-word.
  "pre" on Chrome works with word-wrap, but exhibits different behavior:
  Instead of entire words being moved to the next line for wrapping,
  the browser will cut words in the middle for wrapping.
  "pre-line" has Firefox issues
  */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* Required for wrapping lines in Webkit,
    but not necessary in Firefox if you have white-space wrapping
    (pre-wrap, normal, pre-line) already set */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
var textContainer, textareaSize, input;
var autoSize = function () {
  textareaSize.innerHTML = input.value + '\n';
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  textContainer = document.querySelector('.textarea-container');
  textareaSize = textContainer.querySelector('.textarea-size');
  input = textContainer.querySelector('textarea');

  autoSize();
  input.addEventListener('input', autoSize);
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UDdh/43/light/)

Comment: Still behaves the same for me

Comment: The textarea in your fiddle doesn't change in size when a new line is added, which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a combination of bugs that affect textareas specifically, but the reason is scrollbars. Depending on your text, the addition of a scrollbar may cause your text to wrap onto a newline causing a break. At least webkit likes to imagine there's a scrollbar when calculating scrollHeight for textareas regardless of it being there or not.

To compensate for this, you either need to make the scrollbar (or gutter which has it's own issues) permanent, or you need to get rid of it when calculating things to ensure consistency.

Once Chrome/Edge move it to stable (already available in Firefox), hiding scrollbars while doing calculations will be trivial with `scrollbar-width: none;`.

If you are in Chrome canary, this will work:

```js
document.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const node = e.target;
  node.style.scrollbarWidth = "none";
  node.style.height = 0;
  node.style.height = node.scrollHeight + "px";
  node.style.removeProperty('scrollbar-width');
}, false);
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Assuming you want this to work for all users, the most stable way currently is to set `overflow: hidden;` on the textarea, but beware that scrolling will then be disabled. It also doesn't help to just set it while calculating as the textarea must be redrawn before scrollHeight is updated. You could of course then set overflow to auto at an arbitrary limit. Here is how it would work:

```js
document.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const node = e.target;
  node.style.height = 0;
  if (node.scrollHeight > 200) {
    node.style.height = "200px";
    node.style.overflow = "auto";
  } else {
    node.style.removeProperty("overflow");
    node.style.height = node.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```